# PHP: Updating an associative array though a class function?

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I want to be able to update an associative array within an object based on function input, but I'm at a loss for how to do this. Here's my problem. Let's say there's this data container in my object:

```
private $vars = Array
(
  ['user_info'] = Array
  (
    ['name'] => 'John Doe'
    ['id'] => 46338945
    ['email'] => 'johndoe@example.com'
    ['age'] => 35
  )
  ['session_info'] = Array
  (
    ['name'] => 'session_name'
    ['id'] => 'mGh44Jf0nfNNFmm'
  )
)
```

and I have a public function `update` to change these values:

```
public function update($keys, $changeValueTo) {
  if (!is_array($keys)) {
    $keys = array($keys);
  }
  nowWhat();
}
```

Ultimately, I just want to be able to convert something like this

```
array('user_info', 'name')
```

into this:

```
$this->vars['user_info']['name']
```

so I can set it equal to the `$equalTo` parameter.

This usually wouldn't be a problem, but in this scenario, I don't know the schema of the `$vars` array so I can't write a `foreach` statement based on a fixed number of keys. I also can't just make `$vars` public, because the function needs to do something within the object every time something is changed.

I'm worried that this is a recursive scenario that will involve resorting to `eval()`. What would you recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not hard to do it. You need passing variable by reference and a loop to achieve. No need `eval()`.

```
$var = array(
    "user_info" => array(
        "name" => "Visal"
    )
);

function update(&$var, $key, $value) {
    // assuming the $key is an array
    $t = &$var;
    foreach ($key as $v) {
        $t = &$t[$v];
    }

    $t = $value;
}

update($var, array("user_info", "name"), "Hello World");
var_dump($var);
```

Comment: It worked! I'm still unclear on what it means to pass a variable by reference, I'll definitely need to do some research on that. Thanks!